# TabBar selectedindex button within navigation View

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a tabBar that i would like to use buttons on the called UIViewControllers to set the selected index.

The tabBar was created in the storyboard so my heirarchy looks like this:

```
mainTabBarController Scene
  First Reponder
  mainTabBarController
    mainTabBar
  multiple relationships for the proper ViewControllers
```

the idea is this:

tab A              *tab B*              tab C              *tab D*
    |                      |                     |                     |
navCon1         navCon2        navCon3         navCon4

I want a button on one of the (as seen 1-4, already correctly called) Navigation Controllers that will set the selectedIndex of the parent TabBarController to A B C or D with a button.  I tried adding the buttons pragmatically but i don't understand how to reference the tabBarBontroller in order to force the selected index to change:

**This works fine as I have a function called refreshPage**

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithMarButtonStyleItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self;
                              action:@selector(refreshPage:)
                              ];
```

**This does not work as i am likley referenceing the parent tabBarController improperly**

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithMarButtonStyleItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self;
                              action:[self.tabBarController selectedIndex:1]
                              ];
```

I have given the tabBarController a name, and the tabBar within it .. but i can't seem to use these names to reference them either. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

This is just one problem I am having as I would also like the TabBar children default back to the main tab (or parent View Controller) when i go to another tab so that when i am on TAb A and navigate to controller 1, or 1a, etc, if I go to tab B Tab A will automatically revert back to the top of it's heriarchy ... but that is another question :)

Thank you,
Silver Tiger

Answer (score 0):

Use the first method and in the "refreshPage" method call [self.tabBarController selectedIndex:1].

Comment: nah .. the refreshPage is a separate function that reloads the current page ... I don't want to change the tab in that particular function. I want a separate button that will select the tab as I specify which is why I had it as 2 functions.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize they were different buttons. But the same principle still applies. Make a function called "goBack" that runs when the button is tapped. And in that function set the selected tab index.

Comment: as you can see .. i thought that the second button i created (*backButton) was doing just that ... but it isn't working. I think it is because i am referencing the tab bar incorrectly ...